# Automating a users web application

Tags: javascript, web-applications, iframe, same-origin-policy, browser-extension

I want to help users change privacy settings in a third party web application.

My first thought was loading the web application in an iframe and interacting with it via JavaScript. But the same-origin policy would prohibit that.

To avoid the same-origin restriction I could use a web proxy, but I doubt many users would trust logging in.

I could build a browser extension, but that makes it more cumbersome to use and harder to support all browsers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you need your users to change their security settings to use your site you may be doing something the wrong way. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ilivewithian It sounds like a third party thing to change settings for a web app, not his own web app.

Comment: Even if it is 3rd party, messing with security settings is a big barrier to entry. My question stands.

Comment: @ilivewithian Well he can't exactly rewrite a web application he doesn't have control over, hence the point of making an app to do it...

Comment: yes exactly - trying to help people fix their privacy settings for an external social networking website.

Comment: Well, it's Firefox/Chrome only and requires an extension installed, but you can make a GreaseMonkey script...

Answer (score 0):

You can use OAuth redirect mechanism to support your use case.